# mode function in crystal reports 4.6

Tags: crystal-reports

I work with crystal reports 4.6

I need calc: mode value (alphanumeric data) in a group. Exist a function?

thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Mode exists as a function in every version of Crystal I have used, but I have only used from v6 onwards. If it exists in 4.6, you should be able to find it in the Crystal Reports Designer, in the Formula Editor, probably within the Functions pane under Summary functions.

If you can't find it within the Functions pane, you could check whether the Formula Editor recognises it by entering a new formula as:

```
Mode ({Table.Field})
```

(where `Table.Field` is a valid table and field name within the dataset for your report) and pressing the *tick* button to check whether the formula is valid.

Comment: If 4.6 supports custom functions, you could create a Mode function that will support 1,000 unique elements.  If it does, I'll show you how to write one.